# Ionic2 - Passing data from provider to page

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am learning angular2 and i am trying to understand how to pass data from the provider to a page

Inside the `pages` folder i have a directory called `job-match` and `job-match.js` has this code inside it

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {JobMatchService} from "../../providers/job-match";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-job-match',
  templateUrl: 'job-match.html'
})
export class JobMatchPage implements OnInit{
  private jobs: any = [];
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private jobMatchService: JobMatchService

  ) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad JobMatchPage');
  }


  ngOnInit(){     
    this.jobMatchService.getMatchJobs();

  }

}
```

As you will notice i have a `provider` called `JobMatchService` which has the data i need `getmatchJobs`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class JobMatchService {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello JobMatch Provider');
  }

  private jobs: any = [];

  getMatchJobs(){
     this.http.get('assets/data/jobs-match.json').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.jobs = data;
    });

  }
}
```

When I do `console.log(data);` i can see the data I need but I am trying to understand how can i pass that back to the `job-match.js` and then inside `job-match.html` how i use it?

I will really appreciate any help as i cant seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: any reason why you are not subscribing in the component?

Comment: @suraj I am sorry i am really new to the world of ionic2 and angular2 so i am not sure what you are asking. If i understood you right, i am subscribing to it in jobMatchService

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the http observable from the service.

```
getMatchJobs(){
 return this.http.get('assets/data/jobs-match.json').map(res => res.json());

 }
```

In the component call:

```
  jobs:any;
  ngOnInit(){     
    this.jobMatchService.getMatchJobs().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.jobs=data;
    }
  }
```

Http tutorial angular 2 : [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html)

Comment: thank you man very helpfull I was stuck like one hour looking at this

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the subscribe part from provider to page:

Page:

```
  ngOnInit(){     
    this.jobMatchService.getMatchJobs()
      .subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.jobs = data;
       });
  }
```

Provider:

```
  getMatchJobs(){
     return this.http.get('assets/data/jobs-match.json').map(res => res.json());
  }
```